# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException while file exists on specified location

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, rest-assured

I am creating a test script using RestAssured, java & Selenium. I am trying to create multiple users using POST methods by using the data provided in `users.xlsx` file. I am getting the exception in my utils file given below:

```
package utils;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExcelUtils {
    public static FileInputStream fis;
    public static FileOutputStream fos;
    public static XSSFWorkbook wb;
    public static XSSFSheet ws;
    public static XSSFRow row;
    public static XSSFCell cell;

    public static int getRowCount(String xlFile, String xlSheet) throws IOException {
        fis = new  FileInputStream(xlFile);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
        ws = wb.getSheet(xlSheet);
        int row_count = ws.getLastRowNum();
        wb.close();
        fis.close();
        return row_count;
    }

    public static int getCellCount(String xlFile, String xlSheet, int row_num) throws IOException {
        fis = new FileInputStream(xlFile);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        ws = wb.getSheet(xlSheet);
        int cell_count = row.getLastCellNum();
        wb.close();
        fis.close();
        return cell_count;
    }

    public static String getCellData(String xlFile, String xlSheet, int row_num, int column) throws IOException {
        fis = new FileInputStream(xlFile);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        ws = wb.getSheet(xlSheet);
        row = ws.getRow(row_num);
        cell= row.getCell(column);
        String data;
        try{
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
            String cellData = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            return cellData;
        }catch (Exception e){
            data = "";
        }
        wb.close();
        fis.close();
        return data;
    }

    public static void setCellData(String xlFile, String xlSheet, int row_num, int column, String data) throws IOException {
        fis = new FileInputStream(xlFile);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        ws = wb.getSheet(xlSheet);
        row = ws.getRow(row_num);
        cell= row.getCell(column);
        cell.setCellValue(data);
        fos= new FileOutputStream(xlFile);
        wb.write(fos);
        wb.close();
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

This is my code under `@DataProvider`

```
@DataProvider(name = "createBulkUsers")
    String[][] getUserData() throws IOException {
        //Read data from excel
        String path = "./src/test/testdata/users.xlsx";
        int row_count = getRowCount(path, "Sheet1");
        int col_count = getCellCount(path, "Sheet1", 1);

        String userData[][] = new String[row_count][col_count];
        for (int i = 1; i <= row_count ; i++) {                                       // for rows
            for (int j = 0; j < col_count; j++) {                                     // for columns
                userData [i-1][j] = getCellData(path, "Sheet1", i, j);
            }
        }
        return userData ;
    }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: If you get a `NullPointerException`, then something your code tries using is `null`. And the stack-trace tells exactly what it is. So check the stack-trace of your NPE. Or show it here, so we can check it.

Comment: Btw.: One possibility: In your `getCellCount`method, `row` will always be `null` because you never set it to something else than `null`. So `row.getLastCellNum()` will throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: BTW: you should consider using local variables instead of instance variables...

Comment: @AxelRichter: Thanks. It was the issue with the row since it was not set. Thanks for your help :)